# What is Variance of delta of brownian motion

Tags: stochastic-calculus, risk-management, finance-mathematics

I am new to this.

If variance of Brownian motion b is t, what is the variance of db?

db is delta of b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(B_t)$ be a standard Brownian motion. Then, $B_t\sim N(0,t)$ and $B_t-B_s\sim N(0,t-s)$.

Informally, you can say $\mathrm{d}B_t\sim N(0,\mathrm{d}t)$ where $\mathrm{d}B_t=B_{t+\mathrm{d}t}-B_t$ is an infinitesimal increment.

Comment: I see. What about var(sigma x db)?

Comment: @InfoLearner good question. A constant can be pulled out of the variance if you remember to square it, i.e. $\sigma \mathrm{d}B_t\sim N(0,\sigma^2\mathrm{d}t)$.

Comment: Do you recommend any book or link or online video that explains this concept?

Comment: Itô Integration is covered in every text book on stochastic calculus. Shreve‘s book on StoCal for finance (Part II) would be a good book to start with. You could also google StoCal Lecture notes and I am sure you’ll find many resources introducing the Itô integral.